# Realm database for iOS app with Watch Extension

Tags: swift3, realm, watchkit

Help to understand the issue related to Realm. There is an application for iOS and Watch Extension to it. I was able to connect to each of them Realm base, but when you add information to one - for example, in the iOS application, it does not appear on the Watch. How can I synchronize the display?

I use this function in both cases:

```
func setDefaultRealmPath()
{
let directory: URL =  FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "group.com.gurman.watchTestApp")!

let fileRealmURL = directory.appendingPathComponent("db.realm")
realm = try! Realm(fileURL: fileRealmURL)

var config = Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration
config.fileURL = fileRealmURL

Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config

print("file url: \(realm.configuration.fileURL!)")
}
```

Help please!

Comment: any solutions??

Comment: You've got two totally separated databases - one on iphone and one on watch. They are not intended to synchronize.

Comment: It turns out I need to use the WatchConnectivity framework in order to duplicate my actions in each Realm database?

Comment: definitely. Another option may be doing these actions via CloudKit and iCloud, maybe even storing db file there (worth checking if that is possible) https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/SharingData.html

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice! I just needed to know that using the WatchConnectivity framework in this case is the right solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While in watchOS 1, watch apps were shared extensions of the parent app with access to shared files, as of watchOS 2, this is no longer the case.

Apps on watchOS 2 are completely separate from their parent iOS apps (To the point where I believe they can function while the parent app is closed). As such, it's necessary for you to communicate changes made in the iOS app to the watch.

You can use [`WCSession`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/watchconnectivity/wcsession) in the WatchConnectivity framework to send data between the two platforms. If you have a pre-bundled Realm file containing an initial set of data, you should be able to send the entire file over when the app initially launches. After that point, you should only send the key-value data of what changed to the watch so it remains up to date.

Comment: Thanks for the expanded answer!
One more question - whether it is possible to transfer through the message object like Result <MyClass> ?

Comment: You're welcome! I don't think it's possible to directly send a `Results` object over `WCSession`. `WCSession.sendMessage(message: , replyHandler: , errorHandler:)` seems to imply that it's only capable of sending dictionary objects across.

Comment: And the array can be transferred?

Comment: I can't say for sure; I've never tried it, but I'm assuming it's any object type that conforms to `NSCoding`. :)